# Can't center elements in responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I built a basic web and I'm trying to make it responsive, but I'm having some issues with the slider itself; some elements don't center when I resize the screen; I thought it was because of Firefox, but I tried on chrome and the result is the same.

The slider is:

```
<div id="slider" class="slider-big">
  <div class="vertical-relative-centered">
     <h1>Welcome everyone!!!</h1>
     <a href="#" class="btn-white">Ir al Blog</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the css:

```
#slider {
    width: 100%;
    height: 350px;
    /* line-height: 320px; */
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 0 0 5px #444;
    overflow: hidden;
    
    
    background: rgba(73,155,234,1);
    background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(73,155,234,1) 0%, rgba(32,124,229,1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0px, center center, 100%, color-stop(0%, rgba(73,155,234,1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(32,124,229,1)));
    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(73,155,234,1) 0%, rgba(32,124,229,1) 100%);
    background: -o-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(73,155,234,1) 0%, rgba(32,124,229,1) 100%);
    background: -ms-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(73,155,234,1) 0%, rgba(32,124,229,1) 100%);
    background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(73,155,234,1) 0%, rgba(32,124,229,1) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#499bea', endColorstr='#207ce5', GradientType=1 );    
}

#slider h1 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

.btn-white {
    display: inline-block;
    color: rgb(88, 88, 88);
    background-color: white;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 40px;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgb(88, 88, 88);
    border-radius: 4px;
    transition: 300ms all;
}

.btn-white:hover {
    background-color: #444;
    color: white;
}
```

The thing is that the h1 moves left when I resized the screen, so my solution was to add an overflow: hidden to #slider, and it works quite well, but I got another issue which is because of the overflow, the slider doesn't stick to the header when I resize; then, I removed the overflow and I tried to center it horizontally with a translateX(), but the h1 ignored it.

So, at the end, I don't know how to center the element in a right way and, at the same time, get the slider sticks to the header.

This is the full code in case you need it: https://jsfiddle.net/ilos28/t9ouea7v/

Thanks in advance.

-------------- Added ---------------

This is the difference, when I change the wide of the screen:

Before:
[image]

After:
[image]

Comment: I copied and pasted the code you provided into a codepen and the `h1` is constantly centered

Comment: Yes, that's because of the overflow: hidden; but the issue is that slider separate from the header when you resize the screen. See the difference when you set a wide of 1652 and then set a 1651.

Comment: I removed `overflow: hidden` and it still works: [codepen](https://codepen.io/Rohittt/pen/JjRVpEb) (Firefox 84 and Google Chrome 88 Windows 10)

Comment: I updated the post with two images of how it looks to me. It looks well in your codepen it could mean that it's because of the header that the elements or the slider moves when I resize.

Comment: Just add `position: relative; top: -82px;` to `.slider`?

Comment: I tried to use it just like you said, but then I had to use media queries and I didn't really like them, it could be different if I use bootstrap instead, but I wanted to make a web without depending on it. So, in the end I found a way to do it without removing the overflow: hidden and without using media queries either; I just realize that the #menu doesn't have a height, I set a height: 100% and the space disappeared. Thanks for your help, and sorry for making you lose your time for something so easy.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I just had to set a height 100% in the #menu and the space disappeared.